# notifyAll doesn't awake thread

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a method that's being called from a run() passing threads. I make an iterator for calculating how many threads are passed and use this as a condition for wait()

I have the following code which is run from the threads run()

---

```
public void testMethod(Object x) throws InterruptedException {
    synchronized (x) {
        while(threadsWaiting <= 5) {
            threadsWaiting++;
            System.out.println(x.getName() + " waiting " +
                    " | Threads waiting: " + threadsWaiting);
            x.wait();
        }
        x.notifyAll();
        System.out.println(x.getName() + " passed " +
                " | Threads waiting: " + threadsWaiting);
    }
}
```

---

Example output:

```
Thread 0 is created
Thread 1 is created
Thread 2 is created
Thread 3 is created
Thread 4 is created
Thread 5 is created
Thread 6 is created
Thread 7 is created
Thread 8 is created
Thread 9 is created
Thread 10 is created
Thread 11 is created
Thread 12 is created
Thread 13 is created
Thread 14 is created
Thread 15 is created
Thread 16 is created
Thread 17 is created
Thread 18 is created
Thread 19 is created
Thread 20 is created
Thread 16 waiting  | Threads waiting: 1
Thread 9 waiting  | Threads waiting: 2
Thread 5 waiting  | Threads waiting: 3
Thread 14 waiting  | Threads waiting: 4
Thread 0 waiting  | Threads waiting: 5
Thread 13 waiting  | Threads waiting: 6
Thread 15 passed  | Threads waiting: 6
Thread 10 passed  | Threads waiting: 6
Thread 4 passed  | Threads waiting: 6
Thread 12 passed  | Threads waiting: 6
Thread 1 passed  | Threads waiting: 6
Thread 20 passed  | Threads waiting: 6
Thread 11 passed  | Threads waiting: 6
Thread 18 passed  | Threads waiting: 6
Thread 3 passed  | Threads waiting: 6
Thread 2 passed  | Threads waiting: 6
Thread 17 passed  | Threads waiting: 6
Thread 8 passed  | Threads waiting: 6
Thread 6 passed  | Threads waiting: 6
Thread 19 passed  | Threads waiting: 6
Thread 7 passed  | Threads waiting: 6
```

As you can see all the threads which are waiting do not pass.

This only works in the following way: I pass 10 x objects. 5 of them go to wait(), the other 5 print. After printing x.notifyAll() is called, but no more 'Finished' is printed.

Why are they idle after I call notifyAll()? I know they are idle because Finished is only printed 5 times even after I call notifyAll()

Comment: Can't reproduce your problem. I get 5 `Waiting` and 10 `Finished` in my IDE and in [ideone](http://ideone.com/ODvI0w).

Comment: Is your x all different **instances** in each thread? Because if I change my x from static to non-static, I get 5 `Waiting` and 5 `Finished` as you mentioned in your question.

Comment: @Nier Yes they're all different instances in each thread as I pass it like `ClassName.method(this);` inside `run()` `method` being the method which is in my question and `this` being the x

Answer (score 0):

Full working example create 10 threads, wait if the thread id is more than 5.

```
public class Notify {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Object obj = new Object();
        for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
            Runnable myThread = new MyThread(i, obj);
            new Thread(myThread).start();
        }
    }

    public static class MyThread implements Runnable{

        static final int MAX_THREAD = 5;
        int id;

        Object x;

        public MyThread(int id, Object x) {
            this.id = id;
            this.x = x;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            if(id > MAX_THREAD){
                try {
                    synchronized (x) {
                        x.wait();                       
                    }
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            //Process something
            try {
                Thread.sleep(2000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            System.out.println("Process Thread : " + id);
            synchronized (x) {
                x.notifyAll();              
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: I'm doing exactly the same... I have a synchronized x.wait() and later I do x.notifyAll but it isn't synchronized, and even if it was it doesn't make a difference, I tried. The only difference is that you do all of this in run() whereas I have run() go to another method to do this passing an instance of itself (this) which is the object x. But this is exactly the same. Why wouldn't mine work?

Comment: @GordonFreemanTurtle If you pass `this` as the object x, they are all different instances, which your synchronized is locking on different monitors. Consider passing `this.getClass()` instead.

Comment: @BenoitVanalderweireldt I have a main class where I create a number of instances of class x, class x being the class which extends runnable and has run() which passes the instance of itself to the method in the question in another class

Comment: The problem is that because of the synchronized block when you call notifiyall your thread are not waiting yet ! My code is working because my synchronized block is divided in two blocks with Thread.sleep(2000); in the middle. Instead of synchronized you should maybe use a lock in this case ?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that `notifyAll` is being called before all of the other threads have called `wait`. If that happens, then the other threads will end up waiting on the monitor until it is notified again.

Instead of wait and notify, you should look into something in `java.util.concurrent`. I'd start with a `CountDownLatch`.

Comment: How can threads call `x.notifyAll()` before other threads call `x.wait()`? They are all in the `synchronized` block.

Comment: Some of the threads may not even start before the others finish. Also not clear what's going on with your count variable. Is that some sort of shared variable between the threads?

Comment: @Bill I updated the question. I use it to determine when to stop making threads wait.

Answer (score 0):

```
    while(threadsWaiting <= 5) {
        threadsWaiting++;
        System.out.println(x.getName() + " waiting " +
                " | Threads waiting: " + threadsWaiting);
        x.wait();
    }
```

Say `threadsWaiting` is 4. We pass the `<= 5` test, so we enter the `while` loop. We increment `threadsWaiting` to 5, then call `wait`. But we're waiting for `threadsWaiting` to be 5 or more, and it already is. So we're waiting for something that has already happened.

Waiting for something that has already happened is the most common misuse of `notify`/`wait`.

Comment: Why wait for `threadsWaiting` to be 5 or more? I want those threads on wait to be called `notify`, I don't need to make anymore threads `wait`

Comment: @GordonFreemanTurtle I don't understand what you're saying. What is the condition that you think your threads are waiting for?

Comment: Since they were waiting, I want them to continue with the method and reach the print statement which is after `x.notifyAll()` when they are resumed

Comment: @GordonFreemanTurtle Right, but what is the condition that they are waiting for? To use `notify`/`wait` correctly, there has to be some condition that the threads are waiting *for*. They have to call `wait` if, and only if, that condition is not already true. And any thread that makes that condition true must call `notify`. If you are using these functions correctly, what is the condition the threads are waiting for?

Comment: @GordonFreemanTurtle For example, if you're waiting for a queue to be non-empty, the condition you're waiting for is the queue to be non-empty. You call `wait` if and only if the queue is empty. And anything that makes the queue non-empty must call `notify`. That will work sanely. But if you don't have some kind of condition your code can test for, you will never get the `wait`/`notify` scheme to work reliably. You will wind up waiting for things that have already happened or not getting woken up when the thing does happen.

Comment: I'm trying to make it so whilst the count is <=5 to wait, and when that condition is reached to allow the threads to pass/continue. So if I pass 10 threads, first thread will wait, second will wait..etc until a specific amount of threads are reached and then notify them and let them all pass.

Comment: @GordonFreemanTurtle Then read my answer for an explanation of what your code does wrong. Your thread will call `wait` while `threadsWaiting` is 5. You must not call `wait` if the thing you're waiting for has already happened! If the thing you're waiting for is `threadsWaiting` to be five or more, calling `wait` when `threadsWaiting` is already five is a mistake.

Comment: I understand the problem now. But how else could I get something to check the condition to know when it is ready to `notify` all the threads to resume which were on `wait`? I want to make something like a queue. People should only pass when there is at least `x` amount of people in the queue. So until `x` has been reached, people should wait. When there is `x` people waiting, let everyone pass. I can't really think of some way to know this state and let them all pass..

Comment: I tried to do something like this http://pastebin.com/1JkqLq2p but it's the same thing.. I understand what's wrong but I don't know how to fix it

Comment: @GordonFreemanTurtle You still have the same problem. What's the condition that threads are waiting for? It's not waiting for `ready` to be `true`, since `ready` is local to each thread. And it's not waiting for `threadsWaiting` to exceed `barrierSize`, because you call `wait` (the second time in the `while` loop) without checking `threadsWaiting`. So, again, the same mistake -- no consistent condition and code that will call `wait` even when the thing it's waiting for has already happened.

Comment: @GordonFreemanTurtle Decide what the condition is that the threads are waiting for. Make sure that condition refers only to shared state that all threads can access. Call `wait` only if that condition is not true. Do not call `wait` again unless the condition is false! Call `notify` any time you make the condition true. That is the correct way to use the `notify`/`wait` mechanism.